# VisualForce Page tag

Tags: visualforce

Hi as i am new to development just wanted to ask the question "what is the use of the below tag in the VF page button

**"rendered="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.offline!='1'}"**

Comment: If you are new to VF development, then I will recommend you to go through the [trailhead](https://sforce.co/2U6lL5c) and the [developer guide](https://sforce.co/2CvPhY5) to learn more about it. As for your question, just by going through [`apex:commandButton`](https://sforce.co/2JqKtJw) docs, you will get to find the details. Also take a look on [how to ask](https://bit.ly/2HHdLBj) and [take tour](https://bit.ly/2UMw23O) to understand how SFSE works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rendered attribute shows/hides an element depending on if it evaluates to "true" or "false," respectively. The $CurrentPage.parameters merge field gets the parameters on the page. Basically, when the URL looks like this:

```
https://mydomain.my.visual.force.com/apex/somepage?offline=1
```

The element will be rendered, otherwise, it will not.